# How to make commands using str array in for loop by Python

Tags: python

I want to do something like this

```
CMD_LIST = ['ls -l', 'echo Mama Mia', 'echo bla bla bla']
for i in range(len(CMD_LIST)):
    subprocess.call(CMD_LIST[1])
```

How can i do list of commands in for loop?

Comment: You're calling the 2nd command (index 1) over and over again.

Comment: U r repeatedly calling the same command

Comment: i fixed that)
sry

Comment: Edit your list this way and try: ["ls", "-l"] and subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In subprocess you must provide your command as a list, with the first item being the command and each following item being the arguments.

In your case your code should look like:

```
CMD_LIST = [['ls', '-l'], ['echo', 'Mama Mia'], ['echo', 'bla bla bla']]
for cmd_arg in CMD_LIST:
    subprocess.call(cmd_arg)
```

See subprocess docs here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: nice. Thanks. Its works

Comment: No problem, if it has solved your problem then please mark the answer as correct for completeness :)

Answer (score 0):

CMD_LIST = ['ls -l', 'echo Mama Mia', 'echo bla bla bla']

```
for i in range(len(CMD_LIST)):
    subprocess.call(CMD_LIST[i])
```

Did you mean this?

Comment: its not working

Answer (score 0):

Python lets you loop directly over iterables like your command list

```
for cmd in CMD_LIST:
    subprocess.call(cmd)
```

This is much more readable and avoids errors in indexed looping.